# Why the animation of TextField label on going top so glichy in Jetpack Compose android kotlin

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose-material3, android-compose-textfield

```
OutlinedTextField(
        value = url,
        isError = error,
        onValueChange = onValueChange,
        label = { Text(stringResource(R.string.app_name)) },
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(0f.dp, 16f.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .focusRequester(focusRequester),
        textStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyLarge,
        maxLines = 3,
        trailingIcon = {
            if (url.isNotEmpty()) ClearButton { onValueChange("") }
        }, keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onDone = {
            softwareKeyboardController?.hide()
            focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Down)
            onDone()
        }),
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Done)
    )
```

when we click on the textfield and label goes on top then it is not going smoothly it is lagging.

I was expecting that it will go on top smoothly, but it does not happens.